# snowflake clustering by expression

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, expression, cluster-analysis

Per snowflake [documentation][1] we have the option to cluster SF tables by an expression.

Therefore, it was decided to define a cluster key on the hash(substr(FILENAME, 60,10)) expression

(i) No suspicious information in the output of the SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION:

```
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(hash(substr(FILENAME, 60,10)))",
  "total_partition_count" : 4345,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 4274,
  "average_overlaps" : 0.1022,
  "average_depth" : 1.067,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 4271,
    "00002" : 4,
    "00003" : 12,
    "00004" : 19,
...
```

(i) When I executed a simple query against newly clustered table, the partition pruning didn't happen (it took into account all available partitions)

e.g.

```
select count(*) from <mytable> where hash(substr(FILENAME, 60,10)) = hash('2022-10-03')
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that if I create another column and define the cluster key on it(with the same expression) the SF starts to prune as it is expected.

Comment: Probably because count(*) is purely a metadata operation in Snowflake and so it doesn't need the clustering/partitioning information in order to return the result performantly

Comment: But it works fine if I create another column and populate it from the same expression + define the cluster on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows use of the `hash` function for clustering keys, but it should make clear it's for a very specific use that doesn't apply here.

By wrapping the expression on both sides of the equals sign with `hash`, it makes the predicate ineligible for partition pruning.

With a FILENAME that starts with something like `2022-10-03`, you can use a cluster by key that selects the 2-digit year, then month, then day. Something like `substr(filename,2,2), substr(filename,6,2), substr(filename,9,2)`.

The reason is each string expression gets truncated to 5 or 6 characters (probably 6 in this case), so using a single string will be truncated to `2022-1`. The clustering key should capture all parts of the date.

Comment: Honestly speaking I tried with to_date(substr(FILENAME, 60,10)) - it didn't work
the date format is "2020-06-17" (casting to date should handle the varchar limitation)
Note: I will try your suggestion - thank you!

Comment: It appears that the date is 60 chars after the start of the string. Before you recluster the table, can you provide a complete sample? That may be too many characters in for the metadata min/max values.

Comment: tried with  the "cluster by (substr(FILENAME, 60,4), substr(FILENAME, 65,2), substr(FILENAME, 68,2))" - didn't help
All available partitions were taken into account
Note: the FILENAME is defined as VARCHAR
sample: 
path00/path01/path02/path03/2022-10-05/part-r-00074.gz

Comment: That's what I suspected, the path is too long for the metadata. Is the `path00/path01/path02/path03/` part constant or does it change?

Comment: this is just a s3 prefix - it doesn't change

Comment: Try a smaller test using one of three approaches: 1) use the current column but omit the leading path completely, or 2) keep the current column and add a column that has only the file name, or 3) split the complete file path into two columns, one for the path and one for the file name.  The key thing is to specify the clustering key on only the file name column. Having a common prefix that long makes the min/max metadata look all the same because it's limited in string width.